# Listen to broadcast works in python 2 but not in python 3

Tags: python, socket.io, broadcast, portability

I ported my codebase from py2 to py3 but a specific network part doesn't work.

The snippet listens to a broadcast message from a device (no it is not a response to something, the device is sending this about every 20 seconds)

This works perfect under python 2, but on python 3, the message isn't captured (no error message, just a timeout to the given 30 seconds).

I haven't found something in the portability guidelines so any advise would be appreciated.

Thx

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re
import sys
import socket
import struct


def discover():
    p = re.compile((r'AMXB<-UUID=GlobalCache_(?P<UUID>.{12}).+'
        r'Model=iTach(?P<Model>.+?)>.+'
        r'Revision=(?P<Revision>.+?)>.+'
        r'Config-URL=http://(?P<IP>.+?)>.+'
        r'PCB_PN=(?P<PN>.+?)>.+'
        r'Status=(?P<Status>.+?)>'))

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    s.settimeout(30)
    s.bind(('', 9131))

    group = socket.inet_aton('239.255.250.250')
    mreq = struct.pack('4sL', group, socket.INADDR_ANY)
    s.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, mreq)

    while True:
        try:
            data = s.recv(1024)
            match = p.match(data)
            if match:
                print ("iTach found!")
                print ("IP:\t\t%s" % match.group('IP'))
                return
        except socket.timeout:
            print ("Could not find an iTach on the network")
        finally:
            s.close()
            return


discover()
exit(0)
```

Comment: I thought `recv()` returned a bytes like object.  When I try to call `re.match()` on a bytes object I get the error, "TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object".  I'm surprised you don't.

Comment: You are right, but it doesn't reach the s.recv() line (which might raise an error later). The s.recv(1024) runs on the timeout.

Comment: If you went from 32-bit python2 to 64-bit python3 then the result of `struct.pack('4sL', ...)` could be messed up.  Try `struct.pack('=4sL', ...)` instead.  It would also be interesting to see what the return value of `s.setsockopt` is in the working and failing cases.

Comment: Hi Otto, tried it. Same result, it works with python2 but not with python3. Both python's are on 64bit anyhow.